# Good XMPP/Jabber client library for .NET 3.5 (or 4.0)

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, xmpp

What are some good (or the best!) XMPP/Jabber client libraries for .NET 3.5 or 4.0 development?

I have seen a few decent libraries out there, but most of the good ones seem to be built for Framework 2.0.

(If a Framework 2.0 library is still the best, I'm ok with that.  I'm just looking for the best libraries for a new project built on 3.5 or 4.0).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the one I use [agsXMPP](http://www.ag-software.de/index.php?page=agsxmpp-sdk) and have never had a problem with it although admittedly I don't push it that hard.

Comment: We push agsXMPP extremely hard, often to the tune of >1000 incoming messages per second for sustained periods.  It's never been anything but stable under these conditions.

Comment: the only problem is that it is under GPL/comm. license.

Comment: This library's successor requires a license for commercial use.

Answer (score 10):

Libraries built on the 2.0 framework should work fine in your 3.5 or 4.0 project, or you could recompile them if you want.  [Jabber-Net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) seems to work fine in both of those modes.

Comment: +1 I found Jabber-net to be very easy to use for client programming. I used the 2.0 assembly directly in a 3.5 project.

Comment: +1 from my side too.. Works great..!

Comment: jabber-net is ok for small applications. If you want to push it you will fail. Tested! Also we found several bugs and had to recompile everything to .net 4.0 cause of a .net bug. I will not recommend it for applications having more than 100-200 concurrent users

Comment: Seems like jabber-net is dead. Last release is Jul-2008

Answer (score 4):

Please use [MatriX](http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/) Library for your stuff. The support is really great. Worth it.

Before you buy you could use the trial version and ask for their support in [forum](http://forum.ag-software.de/).

Comment: MatriX is probably the best XMPP library for .Net that you can find. It's based on agsXMPP I think and it it's commercial so it comes with commercial support, Silverlight support, embedded version I think. I haven't used it much but it was one of the libraries I tried and liked the most.

Comment: It's all great but it's extremely expensive. I can't possibly imagine any small company being able to afford that.